# Solving Young Sheldon's 100th episode vanity card

Tags: mathematics, popular-science, rydberg-states

Please define the terms. Below is Chuck Lorre's 700th vanity card which congratulates [Young Sheldon on reaching 100 episodes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young_Sheldon).

[image]

Part 1. Find $x$ in $J_0(x)=0$. --> I guess this refers to [Bessel of the 1st kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Bessel_functions_of_the_first_kind:_J%CE%B1), but [wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=0%3DJ_0%28x%29) doesn't give me a unique answer. What's going on? I forgot this already. I just remember in calculus class that Bessel is like a series solution to some ordinary differential equation.

[image]

I somehow think we're supposed to have $x=2.4041$ and so $yz^2 = 10$ or something.

Part 2. $y=R_y$ --> I guess this refers to [Rydberg constant (Rydberg unit of energy)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rydberg_constant#Rydberg_unit_of_energy). Soooo $y = 2.1798723611035 \times 10^{-18}$ ?

Part 3. $z = \frac{\mu_D}{\mu_N}$.

- 2.1. $\mu_N$ I guess is nuclear magneton?
- 3.2. As for $\mu_D$, no idea. Wasn't able to find in the [list of physical constants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_physical_constants) except possibly...[Bohr magneton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bohr_magneton) ($\mu_B$) ? Or maybe $z$ is the [W-to-Z mass ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weinberg_angle)?

Comment: NIIIIIIIIIIIIIICE THANKS. CLP = chuck lorre productions and YSEC = young sheldon episode count right?

Comment: Correct.  Now, what is 1648777428?

Comment: Oh yeah idk what is that? Hint? @SteveLidie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This is how I solved it on 1 April.](https://www.lehigh.edu/%7Esol0/ewExternalFiles/CLP700.pdf)

Here are the essential details: x = 2.4048 (the first zero crossing of an order zero Bessel function), y = 13.606 (the Rydberg unit of energy in eV) and z = 0.857 (the ratio of deuterium’s magnetic dipole moment to the nuclear magneton value). The answer is 100.0 to four significant digits. Further details, as well as notes on the nonsensical units can be found in the linked PDF (which will not change, and should be read with an awareness of Young Sheldon’s subject matter and the document's publication date).

Note that the number 1648777428 is a Unix timestamp.  The Young Sheldon Episode Count equation only works for that one episode, so I specify the date of the episode's first airing to distinguish it from any future YSEC equation.

Answer (score 3):

So let us assume, following the OP, that $x$ is the root of the Bessel function $J_0(x)$. This function has a lot of roots, but we choose the minimum positive one $x\approx 2.40483$. Let us follow the OP further and assume that $y$ is indeed the Rydberg constant, but in electronvolts, so $y\approx 13.6056980659$. Let us also assume that $z$ is the ratio of the magnetic moments of the deuteron and the neutron, so $z\approx 0.8574382338$. Then $$(y\cdot z^2)^{x-0.4041}\approx 100.226.$$ Not quite 100, but close. One gets *approximately* 100.0 with the following values:

1. $x=2.4041$ (not quite correct, but the card implies this is what its creator used)
2. $y=13.605$
3. $z=0.8574$.

EDIT (April 9, 2022): @BCLC has pointed to my mistake: 0.8574382338 is not "the ratio of the magnetic moments of the deuteron and the neutron", but "deuteron magnetic moment to nuclear magneton ratio". However, [the notation is still](https://physics.nist.gov/cgi-bin/cuu/Value?mudsmun) $\mu_d/\mu_N$.

Comment: Thanks akhmeteli! Why do we choose min positive? Is it some convention?

Comment: @BCLC : "Why do we choose min positive?" Just because we want the end result to be 100 :-) No convention, but this choice seems pretty natural.

Comment: oh lol ok thanks!

Comment: akhmeteli, what exactly are the values for $\mu_N$ and $\mu_D$ please? It seems according to [this](https://journals.aps.org/pr/abstract/10.1103/PhysRev.71.878), $\mu_N = -1.9103$ and $\mu_D = 0.85647$. What's going on?

Comment: @BCLC : Please see my EDIT.

Comment: ok fine thanks but what exactly are the 2 individual values please?

Comment: @BCLC : I gave the link to the ratio, and the link for the value of the nuclear magneton is https://physics.nist.gov/cgi-bin/cuu/Value?mun

Comment: Thanks akhmeteli. Please consider adding https://physics.nist.gov/cgi-bin/cuu/Value?mun and https://physics.nist.gov/cgi-bin/cuu/Value?mud in your answer.

Comment: @BCLC : I am not enthusiastic about adding the links as one can easily find this information.